# Get Count of Rows via https request

Tags: angularjs, https

i get the data for my table via $http request like this:

```
$http.post('/DesktopModules/MyServices/API/PService/LoadPObjectListData', request).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
```

....

My question is, how can i display the value of loaded rows while the request pending?

Answer (score 0):

> I think it's not possible , while the request pending. But you can do it whild the request succeed.

html

```
<span>{{DataCount}}</span>
```

and js side

```
$http.post('/DesktopModules/MyServices/API/PService/LoadPObjectListData', request)
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  $scope.DataCount=data.length
}
```